# Not able to log a fetch's result

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, fetch

I'm currently working with nodejs, I created a server side function that returns and prints data from a database.

```
app.get('/renderMainDashboard', (req,res)=>{ //DASHBOARD DATA
    con.connect(err => {
        if (!err){
            con.query("SELECT * FROM owners", (err, data, fields) =>{
                console.log(data); //IT LOGS THE DATA INTO DE VS TERMINAL
                return data;
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I need this function to be called from the client side, so there is a class that makes the fetch inside the constructor:

```
export default class{
    constructor() {
        this.title = "Dashboard";
        
        fetch('http://localhost:5600/renderMainDashboard') //DEFAULT GET ()
        .then(response => response.json())    
        .then(finalResponse => {console.log('Datos recibidos desde el server', finalResponse);});
        //DOESN'T LOG 'Datos recibidos...' TO WEB CONSOLE
       //.then(console.log('Response from then statement'); //IT DOES THE LOG
    }
//----
}
```

The function actually works, when I try to do the fetch it is still working but I need to log the response. As you may see, there is a then statement with a console.log('Datos recibidos...') but it is not working. Any idea of what I may be doing wrong?

Actual output of the DB:

```
[
  TextRow {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Andres',
    lastName: 'Gonzalez',
    email: 'androsogt@gmail.com',
    personalKey: 'androso+1234-',
    phoneNumber: '35006115'
  },
  TextRow {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Pedro',
    lastName: 'Contreras',
    email: 'sirpedro@gmail.com',
    personalKey: 'holamundo',
    phoneNumber: '41508886'
  },
  TextRow {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Yuhana',
    lastName: 'Melgar',
    email: 'melgar.keyla@gmail.com',
    personalKey: 'COD2002',
    phoneNumber: '37578639'
  }
]
```

Comment: `.then(finalResponse => {console.log('Datos recibidos desde el server: ', finalResponse);});`

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Potentially an unhandled rejection error?

Comment: no, there isn't any error in the console. I don't understand why it does print it when not declaring finalResponse (just doing a random console.log('XD'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't end your request by sending a response. See this example:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

You should use `res.send()` method to end your request and send back data.

Why it doesn't log? Because response.json() returns a rejected promise as there's no response (timeout) and hence, second `.then` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Your express get `/renderMainDashboard` handler is not sending anything back to the client.

Try replacing:

```js
return data;
```

with:

```js
res.status(200).json(data); // provided that data is a valid JSON object
```